# How to tangle a ditaa code block in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, tangle

I use org-mode to tangle code blocks in programming languages such as python into their respective code files. But I am not sure how to tangle ditaa code blocks and execute them to generate figures outside emacs.

I tried to add the `:tangle` tag as follows:

```
#+begin_src ditaa :file ./some.png :tangle tangled.ditaa :comments link :cmdline -E :exports results :results none
...

#+end_src
```

But, nothing gets tangled into the designated file `tangled.ditaa`.

*What is the appropriate way to tangle and execute a ditaa code block in org mode?*

(This is with Emacs 28 in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.)

-- Edit --

There was a prompt when tangling the ditaa block, which was blocking the tangling process:

```
Type M-x picture-mode-exit in this buffer to return it to Fundamental mode.

No comment syntax is defined.  Use:
```

If I enter a random value such as `#`, the block is tangled into a disk file.

*Can I disable this behavior, since there is no comment in my ditaa blocks?*

Also, the tanged file does not seem to remember the `:file ./some.png` tag, and when executed with `ditaa tangled.ditaa`, just generates a file with default name `tangled.png`.

*How can I make the tangled ditaa file output to the same image file as described in the original org mode file?*

Comment: I cannot reproduce the first problem, even if I specify that `.ditaa` files be opened in `picture-mode` through an entry in `auto-mode-alist`. What happens if you open `tangled.ditaa` in emacs? For the second question, there is no place in the ditaa file where the output filename is stored. By default, if you run `ditaa` on `tangled.ditaa`, you are going to get `tangled.png` - it keeps the stem and changes the extension. You can run `ditaa tangled.ditaa some.png` to produce a differently name output file, but there's nothing that Org mode can do about that: you got to do that manually.

Comment: @NickD `What happens if you open tangled.ditaa in emacs?`. I see the ditaa file content as text in "Fundamental" mode. On the second point, I was trying to automate the tangling process and had hope to get the tangled code behave the same way as the code block. But I guess I can hard-code the filenames.

Comment: But it seems clear that the buffer is in `picture-mode` at some point in the tangling, so maybe you can `edebug` the `picture-mode` function, so that the processing will stop at that point and you can get a backtrace with `d` to see how exactly it got there.